# Защита android-приложения от декомпиляции

Tags: android, защита, apk

Вскрывал банковские приложения.. Не получалось. APKTool отказывается что-либо делать. При ручном вскрытии .APK не нашёл даже classes.dex(!). Какие-то сотни файлов .xml и все. Даже манифест не нашёл. Как они это сделали?

Comment: а без интернета приложение работало?

Comment: Да, адекватно реагировало. Росбанк если что